# How to get a vector of the file names contained in a tempfile in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to automatically download a bunch of zipfiles using R. These files contain a wide variety of files, I only need to load one as a data.frame to post-process it. It has a unique name so I could catch it with `str_detect()`. However, using `tempfile()`, I cannot get a list of all files within it using `list.files()`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
temp <- tempfile()

download.file("https://url/file.zip", destfile = temp) 

files <- list.files(temp) # this is where I only get "character(0)"

# After, I'd like to use something along the lines of:
data <- read.table(unz(temp, str_detect(files, "^file123.txt"), header = TRUE, sep = ";")

unlink(temp)
```

I know that the `read.table()` command probably won't work, but I think I'll be able to figure that out once I get a vector with the list of the `files` within `temp`.

I am on a Windows 7 machine and I am using R 3.6.0.

Comment: Hi, what is the size of your temporary file ? It seems to be empty from the error message.

Comment: Well, it should be something along the lines of 200KB, which is the size of the zip-file. How can I determine the size of the temp file? I am quite new to the idea of tempfiles...

Comment: I suggest trying 'testfile.zip' somewhere known so that you can check that the first step goes well. Indeed `character(0)` response seems like it is an empty file.

Comment: If so, you should try `download.file("https://url/file.zip?op=OPEN", destfile = 'testfile.zip')`.

Comment: Doing so, it downloads it to my working directory and shows a size of 276KB. Could it be that the missing file ending `.zip` was the problem? But if I add it, it downloads it to my hard disk, which kind of contradicts the idea of a tempfile, right?

Answer (score 1):

Following what was said before, this structure should allow you to check the correct download with a temporary file structure :

```r
temp <- tempfile("test.zip")
download.file("https://url/file.zip", destfile = temp) 
files <- list.files(temp)
```

Comment: It's weird. The result using this approach keeps being `character(0)`. But the download message is the following:

`trying URL 'https://url/file.zip'`
`Content type 'application/zip' length 282024 bytes (275 KB)`
`downloaded 275 KB`

Comment: Can you please share the exact output copying your code and running `reprex::reprex(advertise = FALSE)` ?

Comment: You will need the `reprex` package to be installed first.

Comment: `temp <- tempfile("test.zip")`

`download.file("https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/observations_germany/climate/daily/kl/historical/tageswerte_KL_00001_19370101_19860630_hist.zip",
              destfile = temp) `

`files <- list.files(temp)`